# How can I create 3d trees in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d

Has anyone had any luck creating 3d trees in QGIS? I want to create a visualisation of a mixed forest stand for woodland creation proposals, but I'm not having much luck with 3D modeling. Are there downloadable 3D svg files are similar?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you modelling? Have you done any research for said data?

Comment: @Erik I've got as far as creating the map in 3d, and can assign height to the polygon shapefile of where the stand will sit. However it would be better to have an actual representation of what the area will look like with trees on it. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I don't think that's possible right now in qgis. What I use to create those pressentations is Blender. It's pretty easy to create a 3D GIS project with it. You can add points and then add trees to those possitions. There are plenty of tree libraries out there.

Comment: It is possible, depending on size. convert the polygons to random points points (1600 trees per ha for broadleaf, 2500 trees per ha for conifer) and then use QGIS2threejs and use a tree model for it.